# Is there a language between C and C++?

Tags: c++, c

I really like the simple and transparent nature of C: when I write C code I feel unencumbered by "leaky abstractions" and can almost always make a shrewd guess as to the assembly I'm producing. I also like the simple, familiar syntax for C.

However, C doesn't have these simple, helpful doodads that C++ offers like classes, simplified non-cstring handling, etc. I know that it's all possible to implement in C using jump tables and the like, but that's a bit wordy at times, and not very type-safe for various reasons.

I'm not a fan of the over-emphasis on objects in C++, though, and I'm gun shy of the 'new' operator and the like. C++ seems to have just a few too many hiccups to, for instance, be used as a system programming language.

Does there exist a language that sits between C and C++ on the scale of widgets and doodads?

Disclaimer: I mean this as purely a factual question. I do not intend to anger you because I don't share your view that C{,++} is good enough to do whatever I'm planning.

Comment: You say that your question is "purely factual", but you are discounting c++ because it "seems" to have too many hiccups. What are these hiccups, and are they valid reasons to discount c++?

Comment: What is the 'scale of widgets and doodads'? If you want real answers to a "purely factual" question you should avoid meaningless metrics.

Comment: And the few things you do state about C++ betray some misinformation. `new` is mostly a beefed-up `malloc` that *can* also take care of initializing the memory for you. With "placement new" and `operator new`, you can decide how and where it allocates memory. And as for object emphasis: A few lines above you state that you consider classes a "simple, helpful doodad". Make up your mind!

Comment: Use `C+`   _Diclaimer: Sorry, I couldn`t resist. It`s 1st of april ;)_

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like the continuum hypothesis, and probably with the same answer. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis )

Comment: Use a C++ compiler, write C code.  Problem solved.

Comment: "C with classses" I believe they called it few decades back :)

Answer (score 29):

These might be the droids you're looking for...

Go - http://golang.org/

D - http://dlang.org/

Rust - http://rust-lang.org/

Comment: @dtech: D has that pointless GC/"Everything inherits from Object"/Values must suck crappery. I've already got C# for that and it actually has decent tools. Go, I admit that my memory of why I discarded it is somewhat hazy, but as I recall, it cut several very useful features.

Comment: the point is that there are features in D someone could not like... nonetheless comparing it to C++, it could be that the OP who made the question does not think those features make D worse than C++...

Comment: -1 for "what C++ should have been". C++ is what it is and if you can't handle it, that's largely your problem. You can deal with it by using a language that suits you better, but that doesn't mean C++ *should have been* like that language is.

Comment: "What C++ should have been". A lot of languages tried that. Java, D and Go are just a few examples. Furthermore D is from ~2000 while Go is from ~2010

Comment: @dtech A friend of mine tried Go about two years ago.  The biggest problem he ran into (and what ultimately made him stop playing with it) was that things frequently broke on non *nix platforms and that there was active hostility in the community about changing things to prevent future problems.  Maintainers being more concerned about ideology than getting the platform widely used is a major problem for anyone who wants to do something useful with it.

Comment: @DeadMG, You clearly aren't in a position were you want to learn. You are in a position were you want to prove you language is the best, which isn't constructive. If you want to know what is wrong, then ask the question, you are in the right website for that, and I'd be happy to answer. Helping people against their will is a waste of time.

Comment: @deadalnix: I dislike C++ so much, I'm actively trying to construct my own better language. That's hardly a position where I want to prove C++ is the best. All I've said is that D and Go are hardly saviours from the promised land, that D has some serious issues that C++ does not have, and that I truthfully cannot remember why I chose not to look at Go. That's pretty objective, as far as I can see.

Comment: D and Go both have the shortcomings of being languages still in active development, rather than mature long-existing products.  D does seem on a good track to provide a lot of the low level power of C/C++ mixed with C#'s nicer features. The GC in it is optional, and the rest of it is built on sound design principles tested in many other languages. Where D is "C++ but better", Go seems to be aiming at "C but better".  It has less high-level construct, but support for a lot of interesting new ideas and a lot of ideology driving it.

Comment: @DeadMG On D, you made 2 meaningful statement : GC is mandatory and everything have to be an object. Both are wrong. It lead me to think that your conclusion is more based on ignorance than on actual knowledge. I have to agree with CodexArcanum.

Comment: @deadalnix: Technically, you can choose to not use the GC. But since you have no way to know or control what library functions or language features use the GC, there's realistically no way to produce a program that doesn't use it. And you cannot create a class that does not inherit from Object. And their `struct`s are seriously gimped compared to C++ values- no inheritance, no rvalue references, for example, so it is impossible to produce something as simple as a value string class in D that is as efficient as it's C++ equivalent. Those are facts about the D language.

Comment: @DeadMG: Making structs with no inheritance is a *feature*, not a "gimping."  It's something they got right, something that pretty much every OO language in history not named "C++" got right (including Simula, the original OO language,) and that C++ got incredibly wrong.  **Inheritance and value types do not mix.**  It breaks object identity, it breaks Liskov Substitution, it breaks the entire OO paradigm.

Comment: And making strings a value type is a similarly horrible idea.  It's essentially the Original Sin of the C language.  (Have you never heard of stack-smashing attacks?)

Comment: struct String { immutable(char)[] data; this(this) { data = data.idup; } ~this() { GC.free(data.ptr); } /* implement some manipulation on data*/ } . Putting aside the fact that it is a stupid idea, this is totally possible in D, and as you can see, it generate no garbage if done this way, so don't require garbage collection. You proved once more that you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Mason: It's gimping. An object's identity is it's address. That works fine for any object, anywhere you allocate it. More to the point, just because *you* can't conceive of value types that make good use of inheritance does not mean that it cannot exist, nor that it should be banned simply because the language designer is too small-minded. If you don't like it, just don't use it- that's no justification for taking it away from those of us who both want to and can use it just fine. Also, stack attacks in C are more because the language is totally insecure and has little to do with stacks.

Comment: @deadalnix: Because that's totally as efficient as one using Small String Optimization, right? Oh, wait, no, wrong. And avoiding a double indirection on my strings sounds like a fine idea to me if I don't need dynamic lifetime detection. And for the record, at least wait for me to reply *before* declaring that I don't know what I'm talking about, because there's a perfectly good chance that I might raise a point you haven't anticipated. So it would be nice if you would be civil.

Comment: @MasonWheeler strings (i.e. char arrays) are not a value type in C. You can't pass arrays by value in C (well, not without adding a struct wrapper and setting a maximum size).

Comment: @DeadMG Again, struct in D are value type, so you don't have 2 indirections. No you see why I didn't explained in the first place, and why I will not anymore in the future. The point is made that you don't know a lot about D, as well as Go, nothing have to be discussed anymore. If you have questions about such languages, as I said, you are on the right website to ask.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: And yet you can allocate them on the stack, making the language vulnerable to stack-smashing.

Comment: @DeadMG: It's not that I "can't conceive of value types that make good use of inheritance."  It's that I see that there are benefits and drawbacks, and that the drawbacks vastly outweigh the benefits.  For example, what happens if you pass a derived object in C++ to a function parameter that accepts an instance of the object's parent class, and then calls a virtual method that's overridden in the derived class?  The base version gets called, because you *can't* actually pass the derived object if it's implemented as a value type!  That's what I mean about breaking the object's identity.

Comment: Are any of these comments useful? If so can the useful information edited into the answer. If not they'll be deleted.

Comment: I think some of the comments expressed useful corrections, like noting that D started in about 2000 while Go is much more recent.  It might also be worth mentioning the controversy over D's choices, but maybe not.  That's something perhaps best discovered by researching the individual language better.

Comment: @mason Wheeler:  Polymorphism is preserved when you pass an object by reference, as well as by pointer.  When you have a function that, say, takes `Base & foo` as one of its arguments, and you pass a `Derived` (whether allocated on stack or heap), virtual functions will work properly.  (Not to mention that the ideas of "value type" and "reference type" don't really apply to C++.)

Comment: Chiming in here with @ChrisF, if you want to have an extended discussion please take it to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers).

Answer (score 19):

There are quite a few languages (e.g., Java, Go, D, Objective-C) that are either roughly parallel to C++, or attempts at fixing problems that the authors saw with C++.

At least IMO, however, all of them work out substantially inferior to C++ for most practical purposes.

Unfortunately, based on your apparent taste for knowing what assembly code will be produced, we can probably rule out Objective C and Java immediately.

Theoretically, I'd consider Go the most interesting of these -- it has some truly original ideas and interesting approaches to solving problems that make some kinds of code much easier. Unfortunately, current compilers don't produce very good code, and there hasn't be a lot of improvement in that regard over the last few years.

That pretty much leaves D as the only one that stands a chance. It's probably the most similar to C++ (of these), but also the least likely (IMO) to fix what you seem to see as problems.

That leaves one obvious approach: use C++, but use only the parts you want, and avoid the parts you don't like.

Comment: +1 for "use C++ and avoid the parts you don't like". And I would suggest to the OP to learn more of C++, people often refuse things just because they don't know them well enough.

Comment: @DocBrown Maybe it's because it's not so easy to know C++ well enough.

Comment: @Malcolm: The problem is mostly shitty teachers. I learned C++ after learning Lua, and the first class I ever wrote was a template. That made it pretty easy to pick up.

Comment: @Malcolm: it is of course hard to learn modern C++ in-depth. But on the other hand, there is absolutely no reason to be "gun shy of the new operator", that sounds just superstitious to me.

Comment: @DocBrown I'm mostly talking about the vastness of features you have to learn if you are to call yourself someone who really knows C++. This is about not only using multiple paradigms, but also doing rather mundane things. Say, as of C++11 there are several kinds of string literals, whereas in Java there's only one. This requires at least understanding of how each works and when to use which. Sticking to the old C ways in C++, of course, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Malcolm: Not really. You only need those literals in relatively rare circumstances- for the vast majority of coders, the two existing ones were fine, if hardly ideal.

Comment: @DeadMG Yes, but you have to learn it somehow. How do you know which feature is used often, and which one is not? As you put it, good teachers are a must (books probably should count, too). And in Java you just have to know what a String literal is. The point is that while new features get added to C++ for a reason, this unavoidably makes the language more complex. And also there is this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/85732/learning-the-nuances-of-a-language-c. Together this makes the language definitely harder to learn.

Comment: @Malcolm: Probably because the concept is *very simple*. Do I need a UTF-32 string literal, or a UTF-16 string literal? Well, that's a pretty easy question to answer, assuming that you know the basics of wtf string encodings are. And those multitude of hard features? *They exist for a reason*. For example, Java's generics. They are *pathetic* compared to templates. Sure, there's less to learn, but that's simply because they're just not very useful. It's like calling anything more complex than Brainfuck difficult.

Comment: @DeadMG You put too much emphasis on this particular example, this is just an illustration to the general point. Also I think you misunderstood what I'm talking about. I never said C++ features shouldn't have been added, I'm just saying that they make the language more complex. It's just natural: the more universal the tool is, the more complex it becomes. The generics you mention is a tool. In C++ templates allow metaprogramming, a complex universal tool. In Java generics are a way to eliminate runtime errors, a tool with a much more precise purpose (far from being not very useful, though).

Comment: @Malcolm: But... isn't the whole point that those complexities are supposed to be a bad thing, rather than a good thing?

Comment: @DeadMG If it were an unequivocally bad thing, C++ wouldn't be so popular. But since it is, then we can deduce that the cons are balanced by the pros.

Comment: @Malcolm: That's not true at all. Popularity is influenced by 99999 things apart from whether or not the language is good/useful.

Comment: @DeadMG "Good" is a rather subjective term. As for the usefullness of C++, I think no one will argue with that. A useful language can be unpopular, but it's hard to imagine how a useless language can reach high popularity. The discussion in the comments has become too long already, so going back to the point, complex tools can be a good or a bad thing depending on the given situation.

Comment: @Malcolm: I think C++ has its strengths (I use at work) but its complexity and mixing of different levels of abstraction is IMO a weakness, especially when used by a large team in which not all the developers follow a strict discipline (this happens in real life). Java may be less powerful, but its code is much easier to debug and maintain. So, yes, _good_ is a a subjective term. If you want to deliver a reasonable product on time and you do not have strong performance requirements, a simpler (and less powerful?) language like Java is in my experience more effective than C++.

Comment: @Giorgio Actually I share your point of view. Personally I would rather have several more specific tools rather than one all-encompassing. I use Java every day myself and find it very consistent (at least, a lot more so than C++). But some people prefer it the other way, and this can also work if they know how to use the vast array of features properly, as you have correctly put it.

Comment: @Malcolm: Yes, I think you are right: there are two approaches (1) different, small, specialized tools or (2) one large multi-purpose tool. Some people can work better with approach (1) while other people are more effective with (2).

Comment: why Objective-C is ruled out by the desire to imagine what assembly code will be produced? If this "desire" makes sense then I would say exactly the opposite: among the mentioned languages Objective-C is the one you can more easily imagine the output assembly.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: If you used only the C part of Objective C, that would be true. Otherwise, well, he might be able to imagine a lot of function calls, but without a lot of work not what would/will be in the called functions. Anything meaningful will generally be (much) more difficult than C++ though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin my preamble was "if it makes sense to say of being able to 'know' (I preferred *imagine*) the assembly output"; stressed this again, I disagree: it'll be harder than *knowing* assembly output of C, but it's easier than *knowing* assembly output of C++. Obj-C runtime is simpler, so you can imagine more easily how what you are writing can be implemented in a lower-level language. But of course here to me the real point is that "being able to know/imagine the assembly output" is mostly a subjective feeling...

Answer (score 16):

> However, C doesn't have these simple, helpful doodads that C++ offers
>   like classes, simplified non-cstring handling, etc. I know that it's
>   all possible to implement in C using jump tables and the like, but
>   that's a bit wordy at times, and not very type-safe for various
>   reasons.
>
> I'm not a fan of the over-emphasis on objects in C++, though, and I'm
>   gun shy of the 'new' operator and the like.

Sorry, buddy, contradiction alarm. Non-cstring handling *requires* `new`. It's a fundamental necessity. You cannot have `std::string` without `new`. And furthermore, `new`/`delete` is exactly equivalent to `malloc`/`free` but *safer*, because it guarantees correct construction and destruction of heap objects (totally necessary!) and uses exception handling instead of a `NULL` return, and is therefore superior in every fashion imaginable. In C++11 it is very possible to write your own `new`-style function, because perfect forwarding allows you to deal with any constructor of any type. If you are gun shy about `new`, then I suggest that you simply don't really know what you're dealing with.

Oh, yeah, and smart pointers make it so that you never, ever, have to actually deal with any of this yourself.

Furthermore, in C++ there is no over-emphasis. You don't have to use any object you don't want to. You can program functionally with lambdas and such any time you want to. Nobody is forcing you to use inheritance and virtual functions- in fact, many good C++ programs rarely exhibit inheritance. Templates are the more powerful and more useful abstraction technique. This is not Java.

Comment: I agree. It is much better to use C++ in the way you want to than to search for a (likely inferior) alternative

Comment: I do not think that lambdas are enough to program functionally. I would also expect to have a function composition operator, currying, and so on. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981400/functional-programming-in-c. To me it feels like almost like doing OOP in C...

Comment: @Giorgio: That question's answers just say "It's hard!". They don't show any evidence that it's actually *difficult*. Why would you want a separate operator for function composition? `f(g(x))` seems to work just fine for me. And I also believe that currying can be done as a library generically in C++11.

Comment: @DeadMG: A function composition operator is a quite well established, basic concept in functional programming. I would expect to find it in a language supporting FP. I find it very convenient (concise) to define a complex function as composition of other functions (e.g. like you do with pipes in Unix) without using variables: k = h . g . f

Comment: @Giorgio: `std::bind` supports such things.

Comment: @DeadMG I will look into it. I hope it can be as concise as k = h . g . f

Comment: @Giorgio: Why not just do `auto k = []( stuff ) { return h(g(f(stuff))); }`?

Comment: @DeadMG: Well, because that would have required templated lambda's. You're conveniently leaving out the `stuff`; no perfect forwarding there yet. And you then have to deal with the type of `k`; it would be an overload set (something you can't assign to an `auto` variable today).

Answer (score 5):

C is almost a subset of C++, so you could just use those parts of C++ that you like and disregard the rest. It is even possible to write valid C that is also valid C++.

You won't be writing idiomatic C++, but that's about as "in-between" as it gets.

Alternatively, you could check out other languages that try to extend C towards something more powerful, most notably D and Objective-C.

And finally, depending on the nature of the project, you can go for a polyglot approach: divide your project into modules, and pick the most suitable language for each part. The downside of this is that you need to get the languages to work together, which may be too much work to be worth the effort.

Comment: Indeed, working in industries such as console game development, where we really wanted "a language in between C and C++", that's exactly what we did. We used a subset of C++ functionality, with certain things off-limits, or more likely off-limits within performance-critical loops.

Answer (score 3):

Just to offer a wild, out of the box answer: if the language you want doesn't exist, why not make one yourself?  There are a variety of powerful language development tools out there, right down the old stand-bys of (F)Lex and Yacc/Bison.  Since you already know C, you just need your "compiler" to output C code, which you then use your existing tool chain for.

This can be both simpler and more powerful than you think.  Start with a parser/lexer for C, then add in the extra features that you think are important.  If jump tables are annoying to write by hand, figure out a construct to express the abstract, and let your interpreter write them for you.  Essentially this is just a higher-level of pre-processor metaprogramming, using outside tools to do the metaprogramming.  You'll always know exactly what the final assembly is going to be like since you know the C, and you know what C your language extensions will expand into.

Obviously there are some limitations to how effective this can be without a lot of extra work.  Adding a full static type system might be a tad more complex than you want to get into, but it's an option you could explore if you find you have a taste for it.  Your DSL extensions are as powerful and complex as you have time and energy to make them, and who knows, maybe someday your extension language will become "the next C++".

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said what C++ features are annoying for you. anyway you could try Objective-C. It emphasizes on Object Oriented instead of Standard Library on C++.

Comment: imho Objective-C is a meager attempt to introduce classes into C and inferior in many ways to C++. Furthermore it is very little used outside of Mac OS X / iOS.

Comment: @dtech: Interesting, a former colleague of mine, who is not a Mac fan (rather a Debian / Linux guy) was convinced that Objective-C was a much cleaner OO extension of C than C++. I have never tried Objective-C though, so I do not have an opinion on this.

Comment: @dtech: Then I humbly suggest you reconsider your opinion ;) Objective-C is about object orientation, and it does a far better job at that then C++, because it introduces message passing. While I agree that the language is inferior to C++ in many ways, it is just as much superior in other ways.

Comment: @Giorgio I agree with your collegue, though Obj-C has also some limits (maybe some of these are gone away with Obj-C 2.0), e.g. I would like to have overloading of "methods" (selectors) — btw I would like function overloading a la Fortran in C...

Answer (score 2):

The embedded world specified [Embedded C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C++), which may be what youy are looking for. They removed things like multiple inheritance and such like. As far as I am aware, it's pretty much died out though.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this in-depth [side-by-side comparison of C++, Objective-C, Java and C#](http://hyperpolyglot.org/cpp) useful. Personally I think C# is a lot cleaner to work with than C++. I have ported several (numerical/calculations) C functions to C# before without too many changes being necessary due to the similarity of the syntax and numeric data types.